# Macro Code to import data

Tags: excel, vba

How do I import from one Excel file to another using VBA?

```
From Req List test.xlsx                   Columns A B K O P L M N U V       
to   Req List test day count summary.xlsx Columns A B C D E F G I K L
```

Both files are on the same path:

C:\Users\msiddique\Desktop

The range for the rows should be unlimited, as the master file is updated daily and more rows get added.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! This isn't a code writing service, so if you show us what you've tried and what errors you've come up against, we're more likely to be able to help. Thanks.

Comment: This seems like one of those things you could just record a macro to do and be done with it (or at the very least edit a smidge so you can change which workbook is source and which is target).

Answer (score 0):

```
Windows("van baan naar AX Nederland.xlsx").Activate
Cells.Select
Selection.Copy
Windows("van baan naar AX Nederland met Macro's.xlsm").Activate
Cells.Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

if you put it in the same window its pretty easy, you just have to open both files.